# or'ing enums that are in namespaces

Tags: c++, enums

I've learned that putting enums in namespaces avoids compiling errors when two enums share one equaly named item.

```
namespace Feeling
{
    enum e
    {
        Happy = 1,
        Sad = 2,
        Blue = 4,
        Angry = 8,
        Mad = 16
    };
}
```

So you can pass it to functions that are declared like

```
void HowDoYouFeel(Feeling::e feeling);
```

But when trying to OR it like this:

```
HowDoYouFeel(Feeling::Happy | Feeling::Blue);
```

I get an error. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the namespaces.

Comment: Have you actually thought of what it would mean to be happy and sad at the same time? Perhaps one of the enums should be `Psychotic` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks for "the best methd", which is a bit subjective. I write `e operator|(e left, e right) { return e(int(left)|int(right)); }` for these cases, to make clear that `Feeling::e` has an orthogonal encoding.

Answer (score 5):

When detailing a problem, you should specify:

- the minimal code sample that exhibits the problem;
- the expected behaviour; and
- the actual behaviour.

In this case, you're missing the error that you get. For example, the following code:

```
namespace Feeling {
    enum e { Happy = 1, Sad = 2, Blue = 4, Angry = 8, Mad = 16 };
}

int main() {
    Feeling::e ff1;
    ff1 = Feeling::Happy | Feeling::Sad;
    // ff1 = (Feeling::e)(Feeling::Happy | Feeling::Sad);
    return 0;
}
```

gives the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘Feeling::e’
```

because the result of the `|` operator is an `int`.

However, commenting out the first assignment and using the second (with its explicit cast) compiles okay.

Answer (score 0):

An enum is nothing but an integer. You could modify the function to use integer (or unsigned integer) as input, instead of the enum.

```
void HowDoYouFeel (int feelingMask);
```

Then a call like following would give no error :-

```
HowDoYouFeel(Feeling::e::Happy | Feeling::e::Blue)
```

Comment: That _is_ one way to do it but I'm not that big a fan of removing the type safety.

Comment: This might not be the best way, but you could add more entries to the enum list to indicate what you desire, such as :-
enum {Happy = 1, Sad = 2, Blue = 4, HappyBlue = 5} 
If all such 'or' results are a part of the enum, there would be no error, since the 'int' would also be a 'Feeling' enum. But this is definitely not a scalable solution. But this will also ensure that the 'or'ing is only valid for cases that you allow. For instance, Happy | Sad won't be valid, if '3' is not in enum.

Comment: @paxdiablo but the cast you propose isn't safe either, since it can yield values that are not in the enum...

Comment: The reason why this is not very good is that the user of the library doesn't know which enum to use when the parameter is just `int`. It's like using `void*` parameters for everything.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out elsewhere, the problem has nothing to do with namespaces, but with using `|` to create an int, and trying to pass that value into a function expecting an `enum`. Even if you "cast away" the problem, you end up with an incongruous value in a variable that claims to be type `Feeling::e`.

It is often more helpful to let `enum` members obtain their natural in-order sequential values. This allows the members to be easily used as index values, and the compiler is often better equipped to optimize switch statements that use them into computed gotos. However, it is often the case that a collection of `enum` members need to be passed around like a set.

Here is a simplified version of a helper I use to turn `enum`'s into flag values. It is particularly useful for code that already has defined an `enum` sequentially, but now wishes to represent a collection of them as a set. First, an example of how it would be used (and notice how solutions that cast your bit operation result into your `enum` type would have to do something strange to achieve a similar result).

```
namespace Feeling {
    enum e { Happy, Sad, Blue, Angry, Mad, MAX_e };
    std::string estr[] = { "Happy", "Sad", "Blue", "Angry", "Mad" };
}

void HowDoYouFeel (const Flags<Feeling::e> &feelings)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Feeling::Max_e; ++i) {
        if (feelings.has(i)) std::cout << Feeling::estr[i] << std::endl;
    }
    if (feelings.has(Feeling::Angry)) {
        std::cout << "The Hulk is in the house." << std::endl;
    }
}

HowDoYouFeel(Feeling::Happy | Feeling::Blue | Feeling::Mad);
```

This is accomplished with operator overloading, a template, and a helper template. The actual runtime overhead with optimization enabled is low, because the code is inlined, so the shift operations on `enum` constants are computed at compile time.

```
template <typename E>
class Flags
{
    unsigned long long m_opts;
public:
    Flags () : m_opts(0) {}
    Flags (E e) : m_opts(1ULL << e) {}
    Flags (const FlagsTmp<E> &ot) : m_opts(ot.m_opts) {}

    bool has (unsigned i) const { return m_opts & (1ULL << i); }
    bool has (E e) const { return m_opts & (1ULL << e); }
};
```

The `Flags` template takes an `enum` type as a template parameter, and provides some simple ways of being initialized. The `has` method is used to see if an `enum` is one of the set flags.

```
template <typename E>
class FlagsTmp
{
    friend class Flags<E>;
    mutable unsigned long long m_opts;
public:
    FlagsTmp (E e) : m_opts(1ULL << e) {}
    const FlagsTmp & operator | (E e) const {
        m_opts |= (1ULL << e);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

`FlagsTmp` is used as an intermediary to gather up all the flags. It allows the flags to be joined together with `|` operations into a single `FlagsTmp` instance.

```
template <typename E>
FlagsTmp<E> operator | (E e, E f) { return FlagsTmp<E>(e) | f; }
```

This operator overloads the `|` operator to turn two `enum` flags or-d together into a `FlagsTmp`.

There are several ways to extend this to better suit your needs, such as adapting the solution to use `bitset`, or adding additional testing methods and operators.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your questions:

1. Nothing to do with the namespace.
2. There are implicit conversions in your call:
   Feeling::Happy | Feeling::Blue will cause conversion from enum to integral.
   HowDoYouFeel(Feeling::Happy | Feeling::Blue) will cause conversion from integral to enum which is not allowed by the compiler, hence the error.